# how to test a selfwritten linux sounddriver?

Tags: linux, audio, driver

I wrote a sounddriver for linux. It looks like it works fine. I tested it with the alsa applications: aplay and arecord
When I am trying to test it with another application (PJSUA) it doesn't work as expected. 
It is to complicated for me to find out if the problem is the application or my driver..

So my question is:
can anyone give me a suggestion for another simple applications with which I can test my driver for a proper operation?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Half of the battle when writing device drivers is in fact writing the test-harness in user-space to properly test them. You should also be thoroughly unit testing your code before it finds its way into the kernel.

You cannot avoid understanding the convoluted innards of `libasound`. You probably want to be testing with a debug build so that you can debug through it.

I recommend you start with the ALSA [examples](http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/_2test_2pcm_8c-example.html) - probably `pcm.c`, and modify it so that it fuzzes your driver.  At the very least you need to check each of the transfer methods (eg. write, write-and-poll, DMA), buffer sizes,  notification-periods, and sample rates.

Comment: How can I compile the ALSA examples (pcm.c)? With a new make-file with the correct CC? then make in the commandline??

Comment: If there's not a make rule in the alsalib make file, perhaps.  Since they are single compilation-unit programs, you may find `gcc pcm.c -llibasound` does the trick.   Obviously, if you build libasound with debug symbols locally, you need to do a bit more work to use the staged version.